# MySQL optimize multiple join query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, query-optimization

I have this query which runs forever, its already running for 30 minutes in MySQL Workbench and counting... Is it possible to optimize it?

```
SELECT `p`.`id`, `ev`.`id`
FROM `participants` as `p`
JOIN `tbl_student` as `tst` on `p`.`First Name` = `tst`.`First Name` AND `p`.`Last Name` = `tst`.`Last Name`
JOIN `tbl_student_session` as `tsts` on `tst`.`id` = `tsts`.`studentId`
JOIN `tbl_courses` as `tc` on `tc`.`sessions` LIKE CONCAT('%',`tsts`.`sessionId`,'%') 
JOIN `events` as `ev` on `tc`.`description` = `ev`.`body`
```

Tables:

```
participants: id, firstname, lastname
tbl_student: id, firstname, lastname 
tbl_student_session: sessionId, studentId
tbl_courses: id, sessions, description
events: id, body
```

Where `tbl_courses`.`sessions` containts the sessions in this format: session1, session2, .... ,sessionn etc

***UPDATE***

I set limit to 10 rows and here is the execution plan:

[image]

Comment: Any query optimization question requires the result of `EXPLAIN ..` statement for the query. Moreover, `LIKE %%` in your query is definitely not going to be able to use any index whatsoever.

Comment: 30 mins? How big is db?

Comment: @Djuro I updated my op with execution plan

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya please check my updated post with `EXPLAIN`

Comment: What do you do when two different students have the same first and last name?

Comment: You need to start defining indexes on the multiple tables involved. Index (firstname, lastname) on tbl_student; Index(studentId) on tbl_student_session; Index(body) on events table

Comment: Also there is clear evidence that you are using comma-separated values in a single field (`tc.sessions`), instead of having an actual relationship table that has one ID per row. This will *never* be fast until you fix your database design mistakes.

Comment: @Tomalak Thats not taken in consideration because it is taken care of from the persons that pass the data to the application.

Comment: You just wouldn't design a schema this way.

Comment: As @Tomalak says, you have too many database design mistakes. You should modify your design it will never go right. (p.e. it doens make sense to join the tables participants & students wuith the name and last names, you should use id to do so and use indexes)

Comment: @nacho the problem is that tbl_student (and all the tbl_... tables) are from another database and I want to keep their ids. Participants and tbl_student with same ids are not the same person, the only way to check if there are the same is the name+surname check

Comment: Sorry, there's no way to optimize the query unless the tables are designed in a way that can do the join lookups with indexes. Your insistence on the denormalized design is what's causing the poor performance.

Comment: Also it can lead to false results. Imagine your `tc.sessions` value is `11`, and the `tsts.sessionId` is `123, 11411, 456`. Probably not what you want, isn't it?

Comment: @fancyPants indeed.... thx for pointing this out...

Comment: @BillKarwin I have to work on existing databases, its not something I designed. I have to move data from one to another, keep the relations between tables and update them to match the data in the new database...

Comment: If it is a comma separated field, then at least use FIND_IN_SET() to avoid the issue fancyPants points out. But you need the meaningful keys on the tables. Even if that means generating link tables to go from the id fields on the database outside your control to your tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inefficient:  ON `tc`.`sessions` LIKE CONCAT('%', `tsts`.`sessionId`, '%').  Are you trying to put an array into a cell?  Don't.  Instead, have rows in another table.

But, assuming your current structure, here are some indexes to help with performance:

```
participants:  INDEX(`Last Name`, `First Name`)
student:  INDEX(`Last Name`, `First Name`)
student_session:  INDEX(studentId)
courses:  INDEX(description)
courses:  INDEX(sessions)
events:  INDEX(body)
```

(You will eventually see why I removed "tbl_".)

Answer (score 0):

try this query. if there are any improvements. I believe your session table is quite huge.

```
SELECT `p`.`id`, `ev`.`id`
FROM `participants` as `p`
JOIN `tbl_student` as `tst` on `p`.`First Name` = `tst`.`First Name` AND `p`.`Last Name` = `tst`.`Last Name`
JOIN `tbl_student_session` as `tsts` on `tst`.`id` = `tsts`.`studentId`
JOIN `events` as `ev` on `tc`.`description` = `ev`.`body`
where exists (
   select 1 from `tbl_courses`
where `sessions` LIKE CONCAT('%',`tsts`.`sessionId`,'%'))
```

Comment: tbl_student_session has ~70000 entries